# converting xavier to glorot in tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert xavier initializer in a tensorflow code to glorot initializer.

I am not sure which one of the following (or other options) is correct?

```
#initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
initializer = tf.initializers.glorot_uniform()  
initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal()
```

Comment: [GlorotNormal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotNormal) and [GlorotUniform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotUniform) are two different initializers. There is no "correct" solution here - you question is ill-posed (even the term "convert" is meaningless here).

Comment: the original code that I am trying to convert from is just using xavier_initializers() so I don't know what's the correct option to go with hence I asked here

Comment: Then the answer below is what you are looking for (kindly accept it) - indeed the [original](https://paperswithcode.com/method/xavier-initialization) form of the Xavier-Glorot initialization was the Uniform one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L31) for `xavier_initializer`, the default is `uniform=True` which suggests `glorot_uniform` may be what you want.

If you are using tf2, you may use `tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()`. `tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform` is just a shortcut function for it: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotUniform